# Calling multiple methods in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I have a `LoginAction` class in which I have three methods `execute()`, `read()` and         `write()`. Inside the execute method I'm calling `read` and `writ` methods using:

```
LoginAction l1 = new LoginAction();l1.read();l1.write(null);
execute file-----upload file from directory.
read and write------------read uploaded file and convert it into excel.
```

In my struts.xml I wrote these steps for calling these methods.

```
 action name="login" class="net.myapp.struts.LoginAction"
 method="execute"
```

but at run time only one method (`execute` method) is    working. How can I call all the methods?

My methods are:

```
public String execute() throws Exception
boolean write(List<String> l1) throws Exception
public String Read() throws Exception
form tag. s:form action="login1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        namespace="/".
```

Comment: The method `execute` is default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this we can use chaining in Struts 2. One action leads to another     one and so on.
Request>Action1>Action2>Action3>Response.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-action-chaining-example/